# How to overclock a CPU in xubuntu

Tags: 14.04, drivers, upgrade, xubuntu, software-installation

I have been wanting to overclock my CPU by about .5 ghz. The only problem is is that I don't know how to do it. A lot of people say it won't increase your framerate but I'm doing this so I can at least run this game that I want, not to increase framerate. Here are my computer specs:

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
8GB DDR3 RAM
Geforce GTX 765M
1TB 5400rpm hard drive

Laptop model: ASUS G750JW

Note: I'm currently using Xubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these commands:

```
sudo ./cpupowerd --freq "0|1800"

sudo ./cpupowerd --freq "0|1600"

sudo ./cpupowerd --freq "0|800"
```

Comment: Those commands depends on the working directory. Can please either use absolute paths or specify the correct working directory.